# cast a response object type to a list C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, system.reflection

i am hitting a webservice which is returning me a object Items in which i have a collection airpricepoint. I have created similar classes items and airpricepoint i am trying to cast the lowFareSearchRsp.Items to IList collection so that i can foreach loop and access the inner collections but i am unable to loop through i cant access the collection inside of fareitems

```
IList collection = (IList)lowFareSearchRsp.Items;
if (collection != null)
{
    foreach (var fareitems in collection)
    {
        items itemsobj = new items();
        Document.airpricepoint airpricepointobj = new airpricepoint();
        airpricepointobj.AirPricingInfo = new List<airpricinginfo>();
        airpricepointobj.AirPricingResultMessage = fareitems.AirPricingResultMessage;
        airpricepointobj.FeeInfo = fareitems.FeeInfo;
        airpricepointobj.FareNote = fareitems.FareNote;
        airpricepointobj.TaxInfo = fareitems.TaxInfo;
        airpricepointobj.Key = fareitems.Key;
        airpricepointobj.TotalPrice = fareitems.TotalPrice;
        airpricepointobj.BasePrice = fareitems.BasePrice;
    }


public class items
{
    public IList<airpricepoint> AirPricePoint { get; set; }
}

public class airpricepoint
{
    public IList<airpricinginfo> AirPricingInfo { get; set; }
    public object AirPricingResultMessage { get; set; }
    public object FeeInfo { get; set; }
    public object FareNote { get; set; }
    public object TaxInfo { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string TotalPrice { get; set; }
    public string BasePrice { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Don't use classes from System.Collections. Use generics...

Comment: Maybe, you can show us the structure of the autogenerated classes of the mapped Webservices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's indeed a web service, then you already know the structure (format) of the data you're receiving. Usually it will be in JSON or XML format; or packaged in a contract class if it's a WCF service.

This means that you can simply de-serialize the data using any JSON or XML serialization library.

Comment: i am getting data in a LowFareSearchRsp obj which is already xml de-serialized, Will it be better to serialize to json and de-serialize back?? coz its quite easy

Comment: What d'you mean by "xml de-serialized"? If you're getting an object from the web service, then what data type is `lowFareSearchRsp.Items`?